# chromium-browser processes' cmdline not available in full form

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, macintosh

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, with 3.13.0-38-generic kernel on a MacBookPro11,2. (late 2013)

I'm trying to get the process ids of all chromium-browser processes, a bit selectively such as only renderers and not extensions. I therefore need the full command-line used to have a better understanding of what each process is doing.

But unfortunately the text is getting cut off. Could it be that chromium is doing this on purpose? I haven't yet seen it on any other process.

```
$ pgrep -lfa chromium-browser
5361 chromium-browser --type=zygote                          
5384 chromium-browser --type=gpu-process --channel=5327.0.1602829409 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=1,11,15 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x0d26 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-versi
5481 chromium-browser --type=gpu-broker                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
5603 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro                          
5612 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro                          
5626 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro                          
5630 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro                          
5639 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro                          
5643 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro      

$ cat /proc/5643/cmdline
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro
```